Create SOAP Web Service with gradle, framwork Micronaut , technology kotlin
It is the first time I am building a SOAP service using Micronaut (gradle), and there is not too much info I found online. All the paths directed me to these libraries:
implementation("com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-tools:2.1.4")
implementation("javax.xml.ws:jaxws-api:2.3.1")
Has anyone experienced the same thing? It would be very helpful if you would lead me to some documentation and examples.
Thanks

Please don't. SOAP is an deprecated technology and as far as I understand, it is not supported by Micronaut at all.
Instead take a look at REST API defined with OpenAPI specification or even use GRPC (which is familiar to what you can do with SOAP).

Thanks for you reply :D, the thing is that the third party service I am trying to connect is using a soap service, and their doc indicates for this type of web service, this is why the reason. If it is any workaround on this, I would really appreciate it

Ahh, I misunderstood. I thought you want to create a soap server service with Micronaut. But you want to implement a client, right?

yep, correct. And I have seen these libraries: implementation("com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-tools:2.1.4") implementation("javax.xml.ws:jaxws-api:2.3.1") , but its a little bit confusiong about the next steps, and honestly have not found any docs for this online
